# Perform Selector causes a delay for applying effect to an UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, database-performance

Good morning, Let me first explain you all the scene behind my question

Currently I'm working with image processing app.In that I'm applying filter effect. There is a number of examples exist in market for this. I check most of them. And I found none of them cause a delay while applying effect. Most of them has decreased delay time by scaling uiimage

But in my case **I don't want to lose the pixels and though want to cut off the delay time**.

In my app it takes about 5 secs for applying any filtereffect.

For filtering I'm using,

```
[<Image_View> setImage:[<Image Name> performSelector:@selector(<effect name>)]];
```

where  is a function name resides into `UIImage+FiltrrCompositions` file.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Are you suggesting that without using "performSelector" there is no delay?

Comment: no, infact how this could be possible without calling performselector??I'm asking for another option than performselector that cause no delay

Comment: Why don't you just call the method directly?  I seriously doubt that your delay is coming from the fact that you are using performSelector though.

Comment: You could call the method directly, like `[<Image Name> <effect name>]`

Comment: I tried by calling it directly, but though it causes delay since there are three other methods invoked from this method

Answer (score 1):

Operations on large images take time depending on the image size, that's not new.

You want to

1. keep your app responsive as well as
2. maintain high quality large image sizes.

If you really want to manage this challenge, I'd recommend that you leverage the logic of your program code by supporting

1. downscaled thumbnail images as well as
2. background threads for operations on the large size image.

This will make your code more complex. But there's no abbreviation to speed up a complex operation on complex data. It's up to you.

For more information about multithreading and background tasks with iOS I recommend [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

Comment: As promised I appreciate your answer. Take +1 for that. And, Yes I do know very well that large images will take time & offcourse its not new. But there is any other alternative for this. I have tried already the first option that you have suggested(i.e. downscaled thumbnail images).But it causes the image to blur when I want to display it as a larger size than the thumbnail.

Comment: Yes, the thumbnail is considered for a fast response to the user and should provide a resolution according to the frame size of your used UIImageView object. For zooming purposes, you'll afterwards want to switch to the large image, as soon as it was reworked in the background thread.

Comment: Yes I/m switching back to larger image then again applying filter effect which causes delay

Comment: @ForamMukundShah for clarification: the trick is, that when you calculate the filter effect for the large image in a <<background thredad>>, this does not cause any delay. The delay only does happen, when you perform this task on the main thread, which then is blocked for user interactions until the task was finished.

Comment: okay got it. Then what is the other alternative? And how do you know that this is running on main thread? Because it is nothing but calling the selector using perform selector

Comment: @ForamMukundShah I've added a link to a great tutorial about iOS multithreading and background tasks in my answer above.